# Is it possible to generate a thumbnail of an inDesign CS5 Document using jsx?

Tags: adobe-indesign, jsx

I am working on an InDesign CS5 plugin that needs to export a thumbnail for each page of a document. For the moment our solution consists in using Document.exportFile, making it export jpeg files with a low dpi. It kind of works but the image quality is really poor (as you would expect).

Is there a better way to do this (apart from making Photoshop do the resize) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You can change the jpeg export preferences before doing the export. Jsx example

```
app.jpegExportPreferences.resolution = 360;
app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegQuality = JPEGOptionsQuality.HIGH;
app.activeDocument.exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, File("c:\\Temp\\test.jpg"));
```

Note that afaik this won't change the actual dimensions of the final image, only the resolution and quality in it. If you want to change the dimensions you need to use Photoshop or do a plugin solution.